# WCF IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults programmatically?

Tags: wcf, binding, fault

I have the following in a config file, and I am trying to find the equivalent bits in C#, as I have a service that is configured fully programmatically. What class/property/method should I look for?

Thanks.

```
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceGatewayBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Answer (score 40):

If you want to do this in all cases, use the `ServiceBehaviorAttribute`:

```
   [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)]
   class MyServiceImplementation : IMyService
   {
      /// ...
   }
```

If you want to do it only in some cases, to be determined at runtime....

```
////////////////////////////////////
// Must include these at the top of file
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
// ...

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Inside whichever function initializes the service host
//
_serviceHost = new ServiceHost(_service);
if (IWantToIncludeExceptionDetails())
{
    var behavior = _serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
    behavior.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
}
_serviceHost.Open();
```