# WCF Exception Marshalling and InnerException

Tags: wcf, nhibernate

I'm using NetDataContractSerializer to serialize exceptions over WCF. When I get  NHibernateADOException (which is unknown for Client) I got FaultException. Unfortunatelly this cause that I lose inner exception message. Is there any way to deserialize unknown exception (or any other type) to specified known type or is there any other to resolve that problem?

Answer (score 0):

You want to set `includeExceptionDetailsInFaults` to true on the service behavior.

See this question:

[WCF IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319765/wcf-includeexceptiondetailinfaults-programatically)

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in web.config to return the exception:

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
```

This tag must be placed within the serviceBehavior tag, usually like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Example of detailed infomation:

> Server stack trace:     em
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    em
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    em
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    em
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     em
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    em
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    em
>   IMyService.GetDataOperation(RequestObterBeneficiario
>   request)    em
>   MyServiceClient.GetDataOpration(RequestData
>   request)

This will return to the client detailed information. **During development** this can help out, but when your service **goes to production**, you will no longer keep this because your service can send sensitive data, like your database name or configuration.